# How do I write responsive regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex-group, regexp-replace

I want to get up to the first digit other than 0 after the dot.
If there is a number other than 0 after the dot, it should be taken as 2 digits. So it must be sensitive.How do I do this with regular expressions or Python math library?
Here are examples

```
"0.00820289933" => "0.008"
"0.00000025252" => "0.0000002"
"0.858282815215" => "0.85"
"0.075787842545" => "0.07"
"1.100000010999" => "1.10"
"0.0"            => "0.0"
"0.000000000000" => "0.0" 
"0.000365266565" => "0.0003" 
"0.000036526656" => "0.00003" 
"0.000003652665" => "0.000003" 
"0.000000365266" => "0.0000003"
```

I tried this

```
def format_adjusted_value(value):
    str_value = str(value)

    if '.' in str_value:
        match = re.match(r'(\d*\.\d*?[1-9])0*$', str_value)

        if match:
            formatted_value = match.group(1)
        else:
            match = re.match(r'(\d*\.\d*?[0-9])0*$', str_value)
            formatted_value = match.group(1) if match else str_value
    else:
        formatted_value = str_value

    return formatted_value
```

Comment: Thinks you don't do with regular expressions: #1 math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a simple `\d*\.(?:[^0]|0+)[^0]`:

```
import re

def format_adjusted_value(value):
    m = re.search(r'\d*\.(?:[^0]|0+)[^0]', str(value))
    if m:
        return m.group(0)
    return value
```

*NB. `[^0]` could be `[1-9]` if you have characters other than digits.*

Output:

```
0.00820289933: 0.008
0.00000025252: 0.0000002
0.858282815215: 0.85
0.075787842545: 0.07
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4FXvd/1)

```
\d*\.       # match digits (optional) and a .
(?:[^0]|0+) # match a non zero or one or more zeros
[^0]        # match a non-zero
```

---

Alternative regex: `\d*\.(?:0+[1-9]|\d{,2})`

```
0.00820289933: 0.008
0.00000025252: 0.0000002
0.858282815215: 0.85
0.075787842545: 0.07
0.: 0.
0.0: 0.0
0.000000: 0.00
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPK4zp/1)

Comment: I'm sorry but there is a problem. If 0.0 comes, it says None

Comment: @theoyuncu13 indeed, the regex expects at least two digits after the `.`, can you clarify all possibilities in the question?

Comment: This working for me; https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730617/22908131

Comment: Note that you can add `return value` if there is no match (see update)

Comment: @theoyuncu13 but why does it work? Don't forget that's questions are not only for you but also for the community, please be explicit.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but there is a problem, if the incoming number is a number like 0.000000, that is, completely zero, it says None.

Comment: That's why you should be clear in the question, you haven't defined that use case.

Comment: Your answer was more correct, I tried the updated code again. I marked the topic. Thank you

Comment: you are right. but I didn't realize this until I tried it @mozway

Comment: @theoyuncu13 all current answers won't match `0.0`

Comment: I think there is one more thing missing. The result is the same

1.1000000109999999 => 1.1000000109999999

Comment: So what about: `\d*\.(?:0+[1-9]|\d{,2})`?

Comment: Yes it is fixed now. Thank you

Comment: There is one more situation. Sorry.
value=0.0000829933
If the number is like this, the result is 8.29

Comment: I updated the question. I think it gives different results as the number of zeros increases.
`
"0.00820289933" => "0.008"
"0.00000025252" => "0.0000002"
"0.858282815215" => "0.85"
"0.075787842545" => "0.07"
"1.100000010999" => "1.10"
"0.0"            => "0.0"
"0.000000000000" => "0.0" 
"0.000365266565" => "0.0003" 
"0.000036526656" => "0.00003" 
"0.000003652665" => "0.000003" 
"0.000000365266" => "0.0000003" 
`

Comment: You forgot to escape the `.`

Comment: what should I do?

value=0.000000365266

When I write this, the result is 3.65. This is wrong. It should be like this: 0.0000003

Comment: str(value) => "{:.10f}".format(value)
I revised it like this for larger numbers

    m = re.search(r"\d*\.(?:0+[1-9]|\d{,2})", "{:.10f}".format(value))

Answer (score 1):

Like most regex issues, just say it in words.  Match "zero dot, followed by EITHER a bunch of 0s and a digit, OR 1-9 and a digit:

```
import re
data = [
"0.00820289933",
"0.00000025252",
"0.858282815215",
"0.075787842545"
]

digs = re.compile(r"0\.((0+\d)|([1-9]\d))")

for p in data:
    print(digs.match(p))
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='0.008'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='0.0000002'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='0.85'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='0.07'>
```

Answer (score 1):

To format a decimal number with custom logics it's better to convert the input to a [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) object for proper exponent-based adjustments. Using a regex for numeric operations is almost always going to end up with unresolved corner cases.

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context, ROUND_DOWN

def format_adjusted_value(value):
    d = Decimal(value)
    exp = d.adjusted()
    return f'{d.normalize(Context(rounding=ROUND_DOWN, prec=1 + (exp > -2))):.{max(1 + (d.as_tuple().exponent < 0), -exp)}f}'
```

so that:

```
print(format_adjusted_value(0.00820289933))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.00000025252))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.858282815215))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.075787842545))
print(format_adjusted_value(1.100000010999))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.0))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.000000000000))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.000365266565))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.000036526656))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.000003652665))
print(format_adjusted_value(0.000000365266))
```

outputs:

```
0.008
0.0000002
0.85
0.07
1.10
0.0
0.0
0.0003
0.00003
0.000003
0.0000003
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/GQYNAc

Comment: Everyone likes playing with regexes for some reason but they almost always hide obscure problems and are anything but clean Pythonic code. Why not use an actual maths library that knows how to manipulate numbers? Maybe because most people don't know how and prefer to play with regexes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import re

def format_adjusted_value(value):
    str_value = str(value)

    match = re.match(r'\d*\.\d*?[1-9]', str_value)
    formatted_value = match.group(0) if match else str_value

    return formatted_value

test_values = [
    "0.00820289933",
    "0.00000025252",
    "0.858282815215",
    "0.075787842545",
]

for value in test_values:
    print(f"{value} => {format_adjusted_value(value)}")
```

Output:

```
0.00820289933 => 0.008
0.00000025252 => 0.0000002
0.858282815215 => 0.8
0.075787842545 => 0.07
```

Comment: but there is something wrong. must be such;
"0.858282815215" => "0.85"