# Use str.format to format numbers with a minimum of 1 decimal place without rounding and without adding additional trailing zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, string-formatting

##### Context

I am receiving numbers as strings in **Python 3** and want to transmit them as strings in order to preserve accuracy so that the upstream server can convert the numbers-as-strings to `decimal.Decimal` without loss of accuracy.

[*Admins: I have repeatedly searched Stack Overflow and other resources can cannot find anyone asking or answering this specific question.*]

##### Question

**How do I use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to provide the given floating point format (below)?** Showing that it's impossible is an acceptable answer.

**Succinctly put, the format is just to provide *at least one decimal place at all times* even if that is just a trailing zero, but never to perform any rounding.**

I suppose there may be a [Formatter class](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/string.html#string.Formatter) solution, which would be acceptable if available, but a `str.format` solution is preferred.

I would be interested in knowing if [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) can achieve this as well. Using f-strings is not preferred as an answer in this context, but it would be interesting to know if f-strings can provide this format (without just packing the demonstrated expression inside the f-string for execution: that's just moving the required code into a secondary evaluation environment).

##### Required Format

To distinguish the numbers from `int` **the format must suffix `".0"` to whole numbers only if they are presented without any decimal places, but preserve exactly any decimal places that are presented, even if that includes trailing zeroes.**

There is an alternative solution under consideration which is to **strip all trailing decimal places that are zeroes but leave one and only one trailing decimal zero for whole numbers (and of course preserve all non-zero decimal places without rounding)**.

Incoming strings can be expected to be valid `int` or `Decimal`. The special case of receiving a whole number with just the decimal point and no decimal places is invalid and will not occur (no need to handle `"42."`). The empty string (`""`) will not occur.

It's not acceptable just to configure to a large number of decimal places (`"{:.28f}".format(1)`).

##### Demonstration

AFAIK this should be the required behaviour. Looking for this behaviour using `format`:

```py
for number in ("42", "4200", "42.0000", "42.34", "42.3400", "42.3456"):
    string = "." in number and number or number + ".0"
    print(number, "=>", string)
```

```
42 => 42.0
4200 => 4200.0
42.0000 => 42.0000
42.34 => 42.34
42.3400 => 42.3400
42.3456 => 42.3456
```

#### Alternative

This alternative behaviour is also acceptable.

```py
for number in ("42", "4200", "42.0000", "42.34", "42.3400", "42.3456"):
    string = (
        number.rstrip("0")[-1] == "." and number.rstrip("0") + "0"
        or "." not in number and number + ".0"
        or number.rstrip("0")
    )
    print(number, "=>", string)
```

```
42 => 42.0
4200 => 4200.0
42.0000 => 42.0
42.34 => 42.34
42.3400 => 42.34
42.3456 => 42.3456
```

Comment: The `str.format` directives are more concerned with converting numbers to strings. When your input is already a string, some simple string operations like you've already demonstrated seems fine. Why do you want to mess around with `str.format` at all?

Comment: Thanks for your question, @wim. I started from a perspective of parsing the numbers. I've demonstrated through the string processing but within the code where it's used it's quite a divergence. I want to just cast it to a number and then express the format. I'm disappointed that there isn't an automatic variable format that can cope with this and it would be far more compact and elegant if `format` could deal with it. I guess I'm also interested in `format` and f-string comparisons and this is an interesting test case.

Comment: What do you mean by *”…and of course preserve all non-zero decimal places without rounding”*? Will you floor or ceil? For example: 4.01 => 4.0, 4.56 => 4.5, 3.09 => 3.0, 8 => 8.0. I would expect estimation to be applied be it flooring or ceiling but probably not rounding.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon, due to the large number of questions about using `format` for rounding to specific number of places I made that statement to ensure the question was understood to require exact representation of the original number without any loss of accuracy whatsoever. I therefore do not want floor or ceil either as these are just blunt ways to round. I'm not sure what you actually mean by "applying estimation". If you mean a reduction in accuracy then no. No estimation. These are exact numbers and need to be preserved exactly. Not even losses due to casting to `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your existing approaches using string manipulations are perfectly fine, if you have to use `str.format`, you would have to calculate the precision you need from the number of decimal places from the given number, which can be obtained from the exponent of the number after a conversion to `decimal.Decimal`. Use the `max` function to ensure a precision of at least 1:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def format(number):
    n = Decimal(number)
    return '{:.{}f}'.format(n, max(1, -n.as_tuple().exponent))
```

or with an f-string:

```
def format(number):
    n = Decimal(number)
    return f'{n:.{max(1, -n.as_tuple().exponent)}f}'
```

so that:

```
for number in "42", "42.0000", "42.34", "42.3400", "42.3456":
    print(number, "=>", format(number))
```

outputs:

```
42 => 42.0
42.0000 => 42.0000
42.34 => 42.34
42.3400 => 42.3400
42.3456 => 42.3456
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/9JbLA0

To produce the alternative output in the question, you can normalize the `Decimal` object first:

```
def format(number):
    n = Decimal(number)
    return '{:.{}f}'.format(n, max(1, -n.normalize().as_tuple().exponent))
```

This would make the test code output:

```
42 => 42.0
42.0000 => 42.0
42.34 => 42.34
42.3400 => 42.34
42.3456 => 42.3456
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hbx3Q0

Comment: This is a advanced and insightful answer, thanks @blhsing. Pretty tricky. It's certainly tempting and I think this really delivers to the actual question. You've broken out the fact that `format` doesn't provide an "automatic" variable precision for this use-case but `format` *does* provide specific variable precision, and you've added the step to calculate that precision all in one call to `format`. It takes an extra line to avoid instantiating the `Decimal` twice but it makes advanced usage of `Decimal` and is natural and elegant. It's hard to choose between this and Anastasia's. Thank you.

Comment: Note that with a `Decimal` object it would be easier to customize the output to your exact likings based on numeric properties. I've added code to produce the alternative output as an example.

Comment: Thanks @blhsing. This is such a good answer I expect to accept it due to its advanced understanding of `Decimal`.

Comment: I'm just thinking it's a useful and sensible function to provide a `normalize` method. The `datetime` library provides a couple of different standard outputs such as ISO format. It might be seen as a bit of a gap that `str.format` doesn't provide some normalised formats. The focus seems to be on rounding and tabular output to fixed widths (for historical string based environments) rather than mathematical support. Notably f-strings have not addressed this either. I'm yet to find an improvement available in f-strings and certainly nothing worth moving code inside strings a la PHP.

Comment: I also found that the server needed some currency numbers expressed as `"1.00"` instead of `"1.0"`. Simply changing the `max(1, ...` to `max(2, ...` solved for that case.

Comment: You may find my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730873/6890912) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730590/how-do-i-write-responsive-regular-expression-in-python) interesting. The accepted answer uses regex-based string manipulations and still couldn't satisfy all the OP's requirements in the end (see comments). Since the logics the OP has in mind is really based on numeric properties of the given number, treating the number as a number makes the solution much less prone to corner cases.

Comment: That's a good example for @wim 's apparently popular comment. I've commented and +1 your answer blhsing. To his credit wim doesn't suggest regexes, and string manipulation can be fine, but why is everyone so skance at using a formatting method for formatting? Or using a number class for formatting the numbers it understands? Seems we all need to be more familiar with `decimal.Decimal` and it's a shame `str.format` wasn't upgraded instead of implementing f-strings. We got a bizarre way to parse Python inside string literals instead of any improvement in formatting numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`f-string` may help:

```
# For whole numbers add .0 if they are presented without any decimal places
fmt_string = "{{:.{}f}}".format(1 if number % format_string = "{{:.{}f}}".format(1 if number % 1 == 0 else 0)
# For Decimal, preserve all decimal places 
fmt_string = "{:." + str(number_str[::-1].find('.') + 1) + "f}"
```

Comment: This is an interesting one, @Simpleiant, thanks for posting. It's like an old Perlism where you see who can work out what it actually does quickest. I think it's doubly twisted for the nested formatting. I can't even be sure it works yet! I appreciate the post thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
for number in ("42", "4200", "42.0000", "42.34", "42.3400", "42.3456"):
    string = number if "." in number else "{:.1f}".format(float(number)) # int(number) also works
    print(number, "=>", string)
```

Comment: Thank you Anastasiya. This is nice that it calls out the tricky case and then processes the rest as usual, still using `format`. It doesn't matter that it uses `float` rather than `Decimal` because they'll only be whole numbers too. This also tends to acknowledge where the functionality stops in `format` demonstrating those limitations. You've really clarified the problem and presented a clean practical solution, thank you. I might end up using this as it is readable and looks reliable in production.

Comment: I still like this answer as quick and practical without complexity. A great robust and readable low-tech solution. Thanks for sharing. I wish I could accept both answers as they are both appropriate to slightly different contexts and demonstrate different ways to use `format` nicely.